# sci-kit image don't load image

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-image

I'm testing for first time sci-kit image. (contratulations for the initative)

```
img = skimage.data.camera()
print img.shape
img_l = skimage.data.load(filepath)
print img_l.shape
img_i = skimage.data.imread(filepath)
print img_i.shape
```

The output I get are:

```
()
()
()
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure how that could happen. Could you display the result from `from skimage import io; print io.plugin_order()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to see the image and variables with Spyder ide. There you can understand what is wrong. I recommend you to install winpython which comes with sci-kit, spyder and lots of more libraries.

```
from skimage import data, io

img = data.camera()
print (img.shape)
io.imshow(img)
io.show()
```